# How is it possible for a contract to automatically charge an amount to an external account?

Tags: transactions

How is it possible for a contract to automatically charge an amount to an EOA?
I mean, in example, in a car rental smart contract (by hours) If balance of the EOA (Who has rented) is enough, how a new price unit (x wei) could be charged every hour.

Comment: I mean, in example, in a car rental smart contract (by hours) If balance of the EOA (Who has rented) is enough,  how a new price unit (x wei)  could be charged every hour.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to 'debit' an amount of ether from an external owned account currently it is not possible. The user has to send the ether to your contract.

But with an [ERC20](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) token you can use approve/transferFrom to allow a third party to retrieve an amount of tokens from your balance.