# How can a Smart Contract pull an amount of Ether equal to its own balance from an External Account?

Tags: solidity, transactions, addresses, payable, address.transfer

I'm writing a 2 Player Game. Rules:

- `Player 1` must place a bet (and send some ether to the contract).
- Then, `Player 2` must match the bet placed by `Player 1`, and send the same exact amount of ether to the contract as well.

Right now, my constructor works well. It allows Player 1 to send ether to my contract.

**I know I can add a parameter to `matchBet()` and require that msg.value equals the contract balance.**

**But is there a way to make Player 2 match Player 1's bet, without any parameters?**

I would like:

1. `Player2` calls `matchBet()` without any parameters
2. `matchBet()` reads `address(this).balance`
3. `matchBet()` pulls `address(this).balance` from `Player 2` to the Smart Contract.

```
    constructor() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Player 1 must bet a positive amount");
        assert(address(this).balance == msg.value); // Contract balance should == Player 1's bet
    }
    
    function matchBet() external payable {
        require(msg.sender != players[0].addr, "Player 1 can't match his own bet.");
        //require(msg.value == address(this).balance, "Player 2 must match Player 1's bet");
        address(this).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
```

I found this: [How is it possible for a contract to automatically charge an amount to an external account?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25757/how-is-it-possible-for-a-contract-to-automatically-charge-an-amount-to-an-extern) but that question is a bit old.

Maybe in the meantime a solution was created?

Answer (score 1):

Smart contracts cannot "pull" Ether from an external address. All transactions have to be sent by the user itself. You can however use [wrapped ETH](https://weth.io/), which is essentially Ether wrapped as an ERC-20 token, where 1 ETH equals 1 WETH.

Both users have to convert their ETH into WETH first. You can make a flow for this on your dApp's website. Then, have both players `approve` a transaction for the WETH, so your contract can use ERC-20's `transferFrom` to transfer the tokens.