# How can I ensure a player matches another player's bet?

Tags: solidity, balances, payable, payments, require

1. First, I want someone to send a bet (money) to the contract.
2. Then I want someone to match the original bet.

(There are many more safety checks in the contract. I just removed them to keep this as short as possible).

Let's say I have this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.10 <0.7.0;

contract test {
    
    constructor() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Must bet a positive amount");
    }
    
    function viewBet() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    
    function matchBet() external payable {
        require(msg.value == address(this).balance, "Must match original bet");
    }
}
```

I can deploy the contract.

I can view the pot (just to ensure everything is fine).

But then I try to send an equal amount with `matchBet` and it always says "Must match original bet".

Maybe I'm going crazy, but I swear this used to work.

I remember I implemented it after I asked this (from another account of mine): [How can a Smart Contract pull an amount of Ether equal to its own balance from an External Account?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/85095/how-can-a-smart-contract-pull-an-amount-of-ether-equal-to-its-own-balance-from-a)

But now it's not working.

Why can't `matchbet` match the bet sent with the constructor?

Comment: Note that, in general, `address(this).payable` doesn't always have to come from a bet.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the ether passed to matchBet() was added to the previous amount of ether.
Write a non-payable function like matchBet(uint betAmount) to compare.